# PHP msg_send cant send more the 525 to queue?

Tags: php, queue

When sending a message to the queue via msg_send everything works fine besides one thing.

Running the below function if there are more then 525 messages put in the queue the browser loads until any message > 525 is processed by the worker script. If i put another 525 messages into another QUEUE ID its no problem. Any ideas?

function que($message, $value) {

```
if (!defined('QUEUE')) define('QUEUE', 16388);

//add message to queue
$queue = msg_get_queue(QUEUE);

//create dummy message object
$object = new stdclass;
$object->message = $message;
$object->value = $value;
$object->id = uniqid();

//send message to queue
//if (msg_send($queue, 1, $object)) {    }    else {    }
msg_send($queue, 1, $object);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

msg_send is just php wrapper for POSIX V msgsnd, default limit for messages buffer is about 16kb (check MSGMNB in your system).
PHP stores messages as simple records - 4 or 8 byte (32bit or 64bit respectively) field, describing type, and message itself.
You can do calculation by yourself, depends on your stored data.
In C-programm you can call msgctl() to change this limit or pass right one on creation queue, but i am not sure this you can do it from PHP.

Comment: Increasing both: kernel.msgmnb = 262144 and kernel.msgmax = 262144 , reloading the setting did not change anything.

Comment: it gives you about 500 byte on message record, it's not too much for PHP serializator, especially for objects. Just try to recieve message from C-client and check how big serialized data are.

Comment: I understand what you mean. but the value was 64kb before, i raised it to 256kb and still can only send 525 messages to queue. if that setting would have affected the amount it should have increased, right? there must be somewhere a setting for the php-wrapper msg_send :((